# Bootstrap spacing between images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I delete spacing between images? I want images side by side.
Now I have this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-1">
  <img src="http://meadowcreeksausage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Italian-Sausage-meadow-creek-150x150.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1">
  <img src="http://meadowcreeksausage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Italian-Sausage-meadow-creek-150x150.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1">
  <img src="http://meadowcreeksausage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Italian-Sausage-meadow-creek-150x150.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1">
  <img src="http://meadowcreeksausage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Italian-Sausage-meadow-creek-150x150.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1">
  <img src="http://meadowcreeksausage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Italian-Sausage-meadow-creek-150x150.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1">
  <img src="http://meadowcreeksausage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Italian-Sausage-meadow-creek-150x150.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1">
  <img src="http://meadowcreeksausage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Italian-Sausage-meadow-creek-150x150.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1">
  <img src="http://meadowcreeksausage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Italian-Sausage-meadow-creek-150x150.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1">
  <img src="http://meadowcreeksausage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Italian-Sausage-meadow-creek-150x150.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1">
  <img src="http://meadowcreeksausage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Italian-Sausage-meadow-creek-150x150.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1">
  <img src="http://meadowcreeksausage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Italian-Sausage-meadow-creek-150x150.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1">
  <img src="http://meadowcreeksausage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Italian-Sausage-meadow-creek-150x150.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>
</div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap adds padding 15px either side on the col-lg-1 class.

```
<div class="col-lg-1" style="padding: 0">
  <img src="http://meadowcreeksausage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Italian-Sausage-meadow-creek-150x150.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

If you dont want them on seperate lines on smaller screens add classes as below:

```
 <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1" style="padding: 0">
      <img src="http://meadowcreeksausage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Italian-Sausage-meadow-creek-150x150.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you, this worked! I see one more thing, when I'm resizing window, there are two or more rows and again there is space between those rows :/

Comment: Sorry, nevermind, my mistake, I had margin-bottom :/ Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can override the pre-set spacing (padding) for `col-lg-1`.
By just adding a `style="padding: 0"` to the same `div`.

Comment: thank you, this worked! I see one more thing, when I'm resizing window, there are two or more rows and again there is space between those rows :/

Comment: Sorry, nevermind, my mistake, I had margin-bottom :/ Thank you for your help :)